# Disable picture-in-picture mode for some app

Tags: java, android

How can I disable picture-in-picture mode for an app (using code) or at least navigate the user to picture-in-picture settings for that app

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  If a user wants to use PiP mode, why would you try to stop them?  You're making your app less user friendly that way.

Comment: Did you do a web search on this? What did you find? What is still unclear? What have you tried? Please take the [tour], especially [ask], then [edit] your question and add your code. What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors?

Comment: @Robert I've done websearch and found nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable or enable picture-in-picture for specific apps by going to

> Android settings > Apps & notifications > Advanced > Special access > Picture-in-picture.

Sadly, this doesn't seem to be a Settings page that you are able to open up programmatically (you can find a list of all the Settings pages you can open using Intents [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html)), and it doesn't seem to be able to be done programmatically- at least for other apps. If you want to disable picture-in-picture for your own app then just add `android:supportsPictureInPicture=”false”` to your AndroidManifest file.

Your best bet for disabling picture-in-picture for other apps is to tell the user to manually navigate to the settings page mentioned above to turn it off themselves.

Hope this helps!